How can I patch u-boot in yocto for the beaglebone black?
I'm trying to make some modifications to u-boot for the beaglebone black, compiling in yocto nanbield.  The two changes I'm trying to make are:

Turn off the delay for the bootloader
Enable booting from a uEnv.txt file on the eMMC

I believe I have the boot delay change working by adding BOOTDELAY=-2 to configs/am335x_evm_defconfig
In looking in to the source code and boot scripts to get the 2nd change working, it looks like there is already support for a uEnv.txt, but as best I can tell, it's trying to find it on the first device, which I believe is the SD card, which I'm not using.  I need it to search in the root folder of the first (FAT) partition on the eMMC.
In trying to get this working, I've modified various files, but as best I can tell, my changes aren't being reflected in my build.  It makes me think I'm not modifying the correct files.  Mostly I've messed with include/env/ti/mmc.h and include/env/ti/mmc.env, trying to do things like change mmcdev to 1 instead of 0.
Can anyone explain how I can figure out exactly which of the hundreds of board specific files u-boot is being built with?  Or, more specifically, how I can get uEnv.txt loading in the way I'd like?
